# Invalid input in C

Tags: c, input, error-handling

I have to write a program that reads in integers from stdin and stops reading at EOF or if there is invalid input. When invalid input is tested, I receive a message saying, "segmentation fault (core dumped)" How would I go about exiting a loop when there is invalid input? Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int num, temp, x, j;
    int i = 0;
    int arr[ARRAY_MAX];

    while (scanf("%d", &num) != EOF)
    {
        arr[i] = num;
        i++;
    }

    for (x = 0; x < i; ++x)
    {
        for (j = x+1; j < i; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[x])
            {
                temp = arr[x];
                arr[x] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", arr[1]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: what's the value of `ARRAY_MAX` ? shouldn't you protect against `i` going over this max value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because on invalid input `scanf()` will return `0` instead of `EOF`, you must check the return value of `scanf()` correctly, in this case for valid input it should be `1`.

If the very first value is *invalid input*, `scanf()` will fail and `num` will be uninitialized causing undefined behavior when you read from it to assign to the array element.

```
while ((scanf("%d", &num) == 1) && (i < ARRAY_MAX))
```

is the way to check for that.

The segmentation fault however, seems to be because you don't verify that `i` isn't big enough to overflow the array. Which I also fixed in the code above.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If the very first integer is input as invalid input, `scanf()` will fail and `num` will be uninitialized causing undefined behavior.